# How to send message body in CDATA with strophe?

Tags: javascript, xml, xmpp, strophe

I am generating messages like this

```
$msg({to: 'user', from: 'me', type: 'chat'}).c("body").t('some data');
```

that generates:

```
<message to='user' from='me' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'>
  <body>some data</body>
</message>
```

but I need this:

```
<message to='user' from='me' type='chat' xmlns='jabber:client'>
  <body><![CDATA[some data]]></body>
</message>
```

do `strophejs` have something or do I need generate them myself? Is it even possible send CDATA to XMPP?

Comment: Why do you need it to be CDATA?

Comment: data can be xml or json so I think I need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send CDATA, but I don't think you need to care about it in this case.  Just pass the stringified data to the `.t()` method and it should take care of escaping it.

There's also no guarantee that CDATA will continue to be CDATA all the way, at least one server re-serializes it as a normal text node with `&escaped;` entities.